# Python: Move data of variable to config ini

Tags: python, selenium, variables

I have `test.py` python file. I use selenium for testing. I have code:

```
login.fillLoginDataAndClick(self.driver,
                           emailField="myemail@domain.com",
                           passwordField="mypassword-qwerty")
```

I need to move all changeable data such as email and password to `defaultconfig.ini` file. So I need to move other credentials from general code to my config for further easy editing.

How to do it?

Comment: I've found, that I can manage variables using `configparser` but i'm newest in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Create a file with `defaultconfig.ini` and then store value in file like below.You can make any level I have given `Auth` level.

```
[Auth]
email=myemail@domain.com
password=mypassword-qwerty
```

2. Then use the below code to fetch the value from file.

   `import configparser
   config= configparser.ConfigParser()
   config.read('D:\defaultconfig.ini')
   emailid = config['Auth']['email']
   print(emailid)
   password= config['Auth']['password']
   print(password)`